# call third party web service from wcf service

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have to call a third party web service from my WCF service library. When I call the third party web service from a test application, there is no problem, but when I call from my WCF service, there is an error:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to xxx.svc/ws.
>   This could be...

I've added third party web service with `Add Service Reference`. Bindings for that web service is generated automatically as:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
   <binding name="WSHttpBinding_xxxService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                     maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
       <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
       <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
       </security>
   </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Bindings of my WCF service are different:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Bindings for my WCF service are automatically generated in test `app.config` file, but bindings for third party service is generated only inside WCF appl config.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the **code** you use to call that third-party web service? Config that you show us seems fine - except we only see the binding - nothing else. You're not showing us the client-side endpoint configuration (URL, contract etc.)

Comment: Inside WCF service and in test program I've tried to call it in same way:  xxx_Ws.xxxClient client = new xxxClient();
           client.Function();

Comment: Activity tracing the non-responding service can give you/us some insight into why there was no response.  Also make sure you didn't hit those quotas.

Comment: turn on wcf trace to get more information http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. The problem was that web application didn't use web service configuration configured in web config file. It always made direct call instead through proxy. So I called web service from code, and input same settings as in web config for web service programatically and added proxy address through which it can pass through my network.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~